# Which kind of caterpillar is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, invertebrates

Which caterpillar is this? It was found in mid Europe during this time (April). Size about 2cm in length. 
[image: Unknown caterpillar]

Comment: That ain't a caterpillar buddy. Thats a *millipede*.

Comment: Caterpillars have six true legs, and only six. That thing looks like it has two pairs of legs per segment, so... like @PrittBalagopal said.

Comment: I see. Any idea which kind of millipede it is? I know that there are more than one kind -- but maybe some "popular" one.

Comment: "in mid Europe" seems a big vague for me, some more details like country, city and natural habitat would be a bit more helpful.

Comment: Actually it's Germany

Answer (score 1):

Based on the body structure and double pair of legs per body segment, this is a **millipede**.

Based on the small size and spacing between body segments, it could possibly be in the [Paradoxosomatidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxosomatidae#Select_taxa) family. You could check by examining the specimen more closely:

> Most species possess a groove or furrow ("sulcus") on the dorsal surface between the keels (paranota) on each segment.

Although the color is wrong, this millipede reminds me of the somewhat-[cosmopolitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmopolitan_distribution) invasive, the [Green house millipede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_millipede) (*Oxidus gracilis*), which is about 1.8 to 2.3 mm long.

[image]

<sup>Source: [NCSU Plant Disease and Insect Clinic](http://ncsupdicblog.blogspot.com/2013/06/); Credit: Matt Bertone</sup>

Due to the color difference, I cannot tell definitively whether this is your species or not. Your poor picture quality makes this more difficult. However, I thought I'd provide this post for you as a jumping off point. good luck!